# VBA - How to copy contents from a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am *very* new to VBA, and am currently trying to copy all data from a variably sized table into a different worksheet.

I'm having trouble copying data from my table (haven't started on pasting it yet, but I'm sure I'll be back ;) ). I've looked for the answer online, but can't find a solid solution that's worked for me.

My code is:

```
Worksheets("ALL DATA").Activate
Sheets("ALL DATA").ListObjects("SearchRequest-19015").Copy
```

And I'm getting "Runtime Error '9'" and it highlights the second line. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: The first idea I would have would be to search this site for `[vba] runtime error 9` and read some of the existing posts to see if they can solve the problem for you. There are nearly 300 existing questions with that error code.

Comment: Try https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables to learn about proper syntax for copying various parts of a table or an entire table

Comment: To echo the previous comment, a  `ListObject` doesn't have a `Copy` method. You'll need to work with a `Range` object - `Range` for the entire table, `DataBodyRange` for everything excluding the header row, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error you chose .copy before .Range
your code should be like this

```
Sub copytable()
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Set myTable = Sheets("sheet2").ListObjects("Table1")
    myTable.Range.Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
    Set myTable = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked for tables! I mistakenly thought what I was copying was a table when I think it's actually a query, so I will have to continue researching, but this served the intended purpose! Thanks again!

Comment: How do you avoid Headers while copying. I want just the contents of the table. Thanks

Comment: instead of myTable.Range.Copy use myTable.DataBodyRange